# How to update vuetify mdi icons ? (Nuxt.js)

Tags: vue.js, icons, vuetify.js, nuxt.js, mdi

I use Vuetify on Nuxt.js. But I can't use some material design icons.

For example `<v-icon>mdi-cog</v-icon>` shows blank. But other icons work well.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
  ],

  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
  },
```

Is it because I have to update it?

And how to update it?

Answer (score 0):

if i don't look wrong, there is not mdi-cog icon, try with mdi-cogs (with the "s" at the end).

Comment: No problem with `cogs`. But the `cog` is available in [materialdesignicons.com](https://materialdesignicons.com) you can search it. It provides by Google.

Comment: I find with https://dev.materialdesignicons.com/icon/cog, but in https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/4.9.95/ that icon don't appears, is weird!